# Calling a Luhn check function when a credit card field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form

I feel like I should not be duplicating the code to gather the credit card number, but I am not sure how best to do it. Any suggestions?

```
$('input[name="payment\[cc_number\]"]').keyup(function() {
    var ccNum = $(this).val();
    ccNum = ccNum.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    setSelectValue(ccNum);
});

$('input[name="payment\[cc_number\]"]').blur(function(ccNum) {
    var ccNum = $(this).val();
    ccNum = ccNum.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    if (!luhnCheck(ccNum)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid credit card number.');
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a [nice jQuery plugin](https://github.com/PawelDecowski/jQuery-CreditCardValidator) to handle credit card validation which might be easier than writing your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  // Always select a context and use it as the second parameter 
  // it will make everything far faster and less prone to errors
  var form = $('form'); 
  var stripCcNum = function(el) {
      return $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  }

  $('input[name="payment\[cc_number\]"]', form).keyup(function() {

    setSelectValue(stripCcNum(this));

  }).blur(function(ccNum) {

    if (!luhnCheck( stripCcNum(this) )) {
        alert('Please enter a valid credit card number.');
    }

  });

});
```

Or for the totally and absolute 1337 (meaning you shouldn't do it for something this simple but it demonstrates some useful techniques)

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('form'),
    handleCcNum = function(doThis) {
      return function() { 
        doThis.call(this, $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
      }
    }

  $('input[name="payment\[cc_number\]"]', form)
    .keyup( handleCcNum(function(num) { setSelectValue(num); } )
    .blur( handleCcNum(function(num) { 
       !luhnCheck(num) && alert('Please enter a valid credit card number.');
    }));
});
```

Comment: I would use [jQuery 1.7's .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/): `$("foo").on({keyup: handleCcNum(...), blur: handleCcCum(...)};`.

Comment: Nice @ANeves - didn't know about that syntax